# R strptime() still returns NA when locale is English_United States.1252

Tags: r, time, strptime

My time dataset HourlyLoad.csv$LocalDateTime are like:

```
07NOV10:12:45:00 07NOV10:13:00:00 07NOV10:13:15:00 07NOV10:13:30:00
```

I'm trying to convert the string date to numeric date, so that I could subset data from starting date 2013-01-01 and end dates 2015-09-31.

I tried

```
x<- strptime(HourlyLoad.csv$LocalDateTime, format="%d/%b/%y:%H:%M:%S",tz="America/Los_Angeles")
```

but x returns NA

I also checked my locale, and it's English_United States.1252. so I don't think the NA is caused by non-English locale.

I also tried as.POSIXct(), as.Date...none of them work.

Comment: `strptime("07NOV10:12:45:00", format = "%d%b%y:%H:%M:%S")`. Your input does not have forward slashes in it, but you are specifying that it does: `"%d/%b/%y:%H:%M:%S"`.

Comment: OMG, thank you so much! I was staring at the code for over two hours. I don't think if I'll be able to figure it out by myself...thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

use

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL","English")
Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "English")
strptime("07NOV10:12:45:00", format="%d%h%y:%H:%M:%S",tz="America/Los_Angeles")

[1] "2010-11-07 12:45:00 PST"
```